# Storing files from subfolders paired with their subfolder name

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science

I have a folder in the following manner :

Folder -> Multiple Subfolders -> variable number of multiple .txt files in those subfolders.

I want to store those .txt files ( not the names of the files but the files itself) in such way that those .txt files are mapped to names of subfolders in which they are present.
I have tried it with a dictionary, but I ended up dictionary with names of .txt files and not the files itself. Please suggest a method to tackle this problem.

This was the code I wrote :

```
import os
h={}
for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(r"path"):    
    for file in files:
        key, value = os.path.basename(subdir), file  #Get basefolder name & file name
        h.setdefault(key, []).append((value))          #Form DICT
```

I ended with names of files instead of files itself.
My ultimate aim is to form a data frame of .txt files.

Answer (score 0):

You can read the data contents using pythons `open()` method and save it in a dictionary.

```
import os
h = {}

for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(r"path"):
    for file in files:
        filepath = os.path.join(subdir, file)
        with open(filepath, "r") as f:
            content = f.read()
        key = os.path.basename(subdir)
        h.setdefault(key, []).append(content)

print(h)
```

I hope it helps. If you have any questions or problems, feel free to ask me.

Comment: It did help but I want to pass those files as an argument to a function which will modify it into a data frame. But when I tried to run that function on these files, I got an error as the opened files were passed as argument not the file. How should I proceed?